# MC75 using symbol.imaging.device libraries for program

Tags: vb.net

UPDATE: 
I found another library in the Windows Mobile - CameraCaptureDialog - this did the job - never did figure out the zero length available devices...

Hi all,

I have a .net application running on a symbol mc75 (motorola) using the scanner.  I am now trying to add functionality for the camera and I am running into issues.

To find the 'devices' you are supposed to use the library's 'available devices' function.

With the barcode it is symbol.barcode.devices.availabledevices and it returns two items (you can scan from the scanner or using the camera device)
However, when I do the camera library it does not find any devices - symbol.imaging.devices.availabledevices returns 0

I can take a picture using the software on the mc75, so I know the functionality is there, I just can't figure out how to get to it programmatically....

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - `Symbol.Imaging.Devices.Availabledevices` returned zero devices but I could use the scanner without problems.

When I installed the [Imager API Support v1.00 For Color Camera](https://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=12683&sliceId=&dialogID=164220767&stateId=1%200%20164212783), `Symbol.Imaging.Devices.Availabledevices` returned 1 device and I could use `Imager` from `Symbol.Imaging` to take photos.